# Display a progress dialog in Native android with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on a project with Cordova in android. While I make a call to a background task in the native layer using cordova plugin I would like to display a progress dialog in from native layer.

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

where context is defined in cordova plugin class as

```
context=this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

but on `dialog.show()` the app crshes.

```
11-01 06:48:25.904: E/AndroidRuntime(19132):    at org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue.addPluginResult(NativeToJsMessageQueue.java:236)
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

You should use context as :

```
mContext = this.cordova.getActivity();
```

This works for me.Hope this helps.

Comment: Check this : http://abstractlayers.com/2013/03/09/phonegap-adding-progress-dialogspinner/ Hope this helps.